# UIView animation clips view bounds. Any way to prevent clipping?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I have a UIView animation that does a vertical flip animation transition from one view to another. The problem is that the view has some overflowed content (achieved by setting `clipsToBounds` to `NO` on the view), and during the animation, the overflowed content gets clipped.

Is there any way to prevent CoreAnimation from clipping the views?

**Screenshots**

*Normal view (notice the paperclip and overhanging rope along the top edge of the map):*

[image: Normal]

*Animation in flight: (paperclip and rope are clipped)*

[image: Animating]

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend placing all the views which rotate inside of a transparent view (kind of placeholder for "map" and "clip"), and applying animation to it rather than to your map view.

Try to set placeholder view's size the way its subviews won't overflow, so you can not worry about hacking *clipsToBounds*.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried: `myView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;` ?

Comment: Doesn't change a thing sadly.

Comment: How are you animating the view? I have done some little tests and my view isn't clipping the subviews.

Comment: I'm using `UIView`'s `+ transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:`

Comment: mm can you give your animation code? I cannot reproduce the problem you are having. Beside this why not just sticking to an animation made with Core Animation? something like: 
    `CATransform3D rotate = self.container.layer.transform;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
        [self.container.layer setTransform:CATransform3DRotate(rotate, M_PI, 0, 1, 0)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.container.layer setTransform:rotate];
    }];`